# How can I use Tableau parameter to show different value in worksheet

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

I created a dashboard for manpower allocation. Purpose of this is to project Monday to sunday workload and assign workers. I created a parameter but I noticed that if I have 7 worksheet to show different day, I need 7 parameter. Is there any way I can create just 1 parameters(list) and select different parameter value individually from each worksheet.

I tried creating 7 parameter for each day. So apply each parameter to each worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated field to interact with all the worksheets as a filter and have it driven by a single selection of let's say a `day_of_week` parameter.

### Create the Parameter:

When you create your `day_of_week` parameter, set it up as an integer and a list so it looks similar to the grid below:

| Value | Display As |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday |
| 2 | Tuesday |
| 3 | Wednesday |
| ... | ... |
| 8 | All Days |

### Create the Logic:

Let's create a calculated field `day_of_week_logic` to hold all the use cases for our parameter.

```
CASE [day_of_week]
WHEN 1 THEN IF DAY([your_date_field]) = "Monday" THEN [your_date_field] END
WHEN 2 THEN IF DAY([your_date_field]) = "Tuesday" THEN [your_date_field] END
...
WHEN 8 THEN [your_date_field]
END
```

***Note**: I did this in my head; there may be errors when comparing different types ie. comparing strings and integers/ dates and or aggregated values to non-aggregated values*

Lets break down the calculation above. First grab our parameter then based on our selection of it (say we choose "Monday") it will return a value (in this case, "1"). We then write what we expect Tableau to return when that value is present. We want to return all Mondays so we use the `DAY()` function to find our Mondays and return all the dates that meet this criteria.

Although it was not specified in your question above, if you only want a single week, this solution will still work if you filter ***ALL*** the data touching these sheets for a specific, albeit valid, date range.

### Apply to Worksheets:

1. Drag our `day_of_week_logic` to the filter pane and set to "True".
2. Right click and choose *Apply to Worksheets*, select all applicable worksheets.
3. Show `day_of_week` parameter on dashboard.